# Chrome Default Popup How to use it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css, popup

Is it possible to use the chrome popup which is seen in the settings page in my web page
[image]

Comment: Nearly everything in Chrome is plain HTML/CSS/JS. You can use all of Chrome's developer tools to find out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.showModalDialog()`

however, not recommended - [window.showModalDialog: What It is and Why You Should Never Use It](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/)